# Windows Store: One of your Packages can’t be encrypted because the targeted device family MinVersion doesn’t support encryption

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-store

When I´m uploading a package to the Windows store I´ll get the following error message:

> One or more of your packages can’t be encrypted because the targeted
> device family MinVersion doesn’t support encryption. To resolve this
> issue, upload only packages targeting MinVersion 10.0.14393.0 or
> later.

My only package is set to MinVersion 10.0.14393.0 in the package-manifest like this:

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Xbox" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
```

Could it be that Nugetpackages (I´m using PCLStorage, PCLCrypto, AWSS3SDK and some others) that are linked to the package are set to a lower minversion? Or why do I get this error message from the partner center?

Comment: Would you like to change the minversion a little bit higher than 14393?  Have you checked if there are Nuget packages that target version is lower than 14393?

Comment: Hi Roy. Yes setting the minversion to 10.0.16299.0 does the trick. So I guess the error message is not quite right but with the workaround it doesn´t really matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please change the minversion of your app a little bit higher than 14393, like 16399. That will help to avoid this issue.